# Can't add a simple TableView to Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

[image]

Right now my StoryBoard is like this:

**X->X->X**

I want it to be like this:

**X->Y->X->X**

Y will be a simple Tableview connected to the navigation controller on one end and to masterviewcontroller on the other end with a basic cell pushing to it. I don't want to change anything in the app besides that.

but when I'm trying to do so I'm getting an error:

`ScaryBugs[1768:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setBugs:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71d0940'`

I'm guessing it's because I don't completely understand what those 3 lines are doing.

**AppDelegate.m:**

```
UINavigationController * navController = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
MasterViewController * masterController = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
masterController.bugs = bugs;
```

[Source of code](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: I don't think this code makes any sense, and certainly doesn't do what you say you want to do. The error doesn't seem to come from this code, since you're not accessing an array at index 1. If you have more code in your app delegate, you should post it all.

Comment: Yeah, and "I want to add a new table view between the navigation controller and "bugsTableView" is a shuck, sorry )

Comment: I edited the first post and gave a link for the source code.

Comment: Also added a picture and a better explanation.

Comment: Is your code now exactly like the code your referenced? How are you populating the rows of this new table view? On what line do you get that error message?

Comment: Exactly the same code. The only thing I did was to download the code from here: http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/downloads/ScaryBugs1b.zip and tried to add a table view between the navigation and MasterView without getting an error. I'm not populating the rows yet. Just conected an empty basic cell to MasterViewController. On what line I'm getting the error: I believe it's this one on AppDelegate.m: `    masterController.bugs = bugs;`

Comment: Ok, you're getting this error (the new one in your edited post) because bugs is a property of the original MasterViewController, and now you're defining your new controller (the one at index 0 of the navigation controller) as masterController, and it doesn't have a bugs property. You can't just plop in a new controller into the scheme without changing the code. What is the purpose of this new controller anyway?

Comment: I figured that no ploping is allowed.. That's why I'm trying to understand it better :). The new controller will be a simple  list of names such as bats, sharks etc' and will connect to lists similar to bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That third line is just assigning the bugs property of the masterController to the array that was created in the app delegate with the local variable name, bugs. The first 2 lines are just getting references to the controllers that were created in the storyboard.

By putting another controller in as the root view controller of the navigation controller, you're screwing up the references. After adding it, the MasterController is now not even instantiated until you push to it, so there's no way to set its bugs property. Your new controller just doesn't belong there. It wouldn't really make sense to push from your list of bats, sharks, etc. to a list of bugs --  usually, that push (especially if it's from a table view cell) means you're going to present some information that gives more details about the cell you touched. IF you're trying to expand upon the tutorial, you really need to change the overall structure of the app, and that could require quite a few changes in the code.